# No quick action available here

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

When i create a xamarin android blank app everything is fine but when i add some activities The activity base class id black instead of green and also there won't be any intellisense suggestion can anyone help me thanks in advance,
and also added

Xamarin.Firebase.Auth

Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvbDf.png)

Comment: Check this link how to set the intellisense  in xamarin Android https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/questions/enable-axml-intellisense/

Comment: Which version of Xamarin are you using? Try to update it.

Comment: @Grace  My xamarin version is 7.3.1.2